# Should I use a single piece of code that works for all situations or multiple pieces of code that work for specific situations?

Tags: design-patterns

I am working on a game that has Upgrades for the player, such as Health Regeneration and Max Health. In an Upgrades screen, for each upgrade, I list the name and level and have increase and decrease buttons to increase and decrease the level. Upgrades are bought with a currency called gems. 1 gem can increase the level of an upgrade by 1.

The requirements for increasing the level of a certain upgrade are that the number of gems the player has is greater than 0 and the upgrade's level is not equal to the max level.

The requirement for decreasing the level of a certain upgrade is that the upgrade's level is not 0.

When an upgrade level increase or decrease is available, I want the increase button or decrease button to be green. When it is not available, I want it to be red.

I have enable and disable functions for the increase and decrease buttons in the Upgrade class which turn the buttons green/red. The enable/disable functions can be called even if the button was already enabled or disabled, or if the button was not made yet (it only removes/adds the green button/red image if that action has not been done yet).

I do not know which strategy I should use for calling the button enabling/disabling functions. I will explain 2 strategies here.

**Strategy 1**

This is the strategy of using a single piece of code that works for all situations. Every time an upgrade button is pressed, or when the reset button is pressed, both buttons on all upgrades are checked and enabled or disabled depending on the conditions I mentioned above, regardless of whether doing certain checks were necessary or not.

Pros: easy to code, simple, and the code is all together.

**Strategy 2**

This is the strategy of writing multiple pieces of code that work for specific situations. Code that only applies to one upgrade would be written in the Upgrade class, not in the Main class. For example, when the level on a certain upgrade is increased, I would only check that one upgrade to see if it is maxed, and then check in the Main class if we have gems. If we didn't, all upgrade increase buttons would be disabled.

Pros: Buttons are checked only when they need to be checked.

At this point what I would choose to do is mostly Strategy 1, except I would use 2 functions instead of one. One function would be for when an upgrade is increased, and then I would check if upgrade increase buttons need to be disabled and if upgrade decrease buttons need to be enabled. The other function would be for the opposite scenario. Right now I am a little worried about each strategy. Strategy 1 seems like it requires more run time work than is necessary (it checks buttons that don't need to be checked), although the actual performance impact would be negligible. However, Strategy 2 seems like it requires much more coding work than is necessary. For example, when I press the reset button, Strategy 1 would handle it just fine with the same code, but in Strategy 2 I would have to explicitly enable all upgrade increase buttons and disable all upgrade decrease buttons, which seems unnatural. I would like to know what I should do: Strategy 1, Strategy 2, or my combination that I mentioned in the beginning of this paragraph?

Comment: Definitely one or the other.  Or maybe a combination.  Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The over-arching strategy (including in deciding when to apply either of your strategies needs) to be "Avoid coding the same thing multiple times".   If you code something more than once, it is an opportunity to have several unintended variations (e.g. a set of errors in one version and not in another) and a maintenance burden (if you change one, it is necessary to go through all the other places where the same logic is coded, and update each).

Use strategy 1 to handle actions that - according to your design - are applicable to all situations.

Use strategy 2 to handle actions that - according to your design - are specific to only a few situations.

You can also combine the strategies, and collect meaningful sets of actions (meaningful in the sense that code which employs one action will probably need to employ other particular actions) at various points.